# Why is the RGB of picked pink ffbfbf and not ffc0cb?

Tags: color

Picking the RGB values with GIMP from p. 18 of `xcolor.pdf` yields `ffbfbf`:

[image: screenshot]

You get the same `ffbfbf` if you run, say,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% even if you use the options [x11names] or [rgb].
\begin{document}
\textcolor{pink}{\rule{1em}{1em}}
\end{document}
```

through `pdflatex` and let GIMP pick the color from the PDF. However, according to `rgb.txt`, the RGB value of pink should be `255 192 203` in decimal, i.e., `ffc0cb` in  hexadecimal, shouldn't it?

Not all colors are altered. E.g., `LightBlue1` is the same `bfefff` both according to `/etc/X11/rgb.txt` and when picked by GIMP from p. 44. of `xcolor.pdf`.

PS. Bug reports against `xcolor` and `X11` submitted: https://github.com/latex3/xcolor/issues/24 and https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/rgb/-/issues/1 .

Answer (score 5):

pink is defined as rgb(1,.75,.75) by xcolor (you can find the definition in xcolor.sty).

`0.75 x 255 = 191.25` and `191 = BF (hex)` so the values picked up by your color picker looks ok. If you want pink to be more like you value define your own color (or redefine pink):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{pink}{\rule{1em}{1em}}

\definecolor{mypink}{HTML}{FFC0CB}
\textcolor{mypink}{\rule{1em}{1em}}

\end{document}
```

This gives in the PDF `1 0.75294 0.79608`  as rgb values.

Comment: I undertstand the question: why xcolor pink is not equal to X11 pink from rgb.txt. The fact, that they differ (defined in xcolor as 1,.75,.75) is known. Is it mistake or intent?

Comment: @wipet Such "why" questions are rather senseless. The value of "pink" is not some universal constant. xcolor is around 20 years old, and why someone at this time decided about which values to use don't matter. It is a sort of pink and if you want another redefine the color.

Comment: X11 is older, since 1987. All others RGB colors defined in xcolor are the same as in rgb.txt, only pink doesn't. It seems that rgb.txt was an etalon for colors in computers but authors of xcolor decided that pink was not good pink.

Comment: @wipet Should we pin{g|k} the folks mentioned in xcolor.sty and submit an issue ?  In fact, for an application I have in mind, the correspondence between name and RGB value matters …

Comment: The “why” questions may make sense to one person and little sense to another. Still, this doesn't make them bad questions per se. Thank you for an answer in any case! The point is: with `[x11names]` you might probably expect that also the RGB values from X11 would be in effect, and the option would not concern the names only. The discrepancy is embarrassing.

Comment: @GeekestGeek sorry you can try but I doubt that we will change it. The color has been like that for 20 years. Also if you want reliable colors for an application, then define your own names.

Comment: I doubt that the X11 world (and everything relying on it) will change it either. Still, having the same name for two different things is not good at all.

Comment: In fact, not 20 years, but slightly less than 17 years, as pink was added to the set of predefined colors in v2.05 on 2005-09-30 according to p. 65 of xcolor.pdf. Still, if it's a bug, it's not that old till it got discovered; the record is, IMHO, over 37 years (cf. https://e-merge.co.za/worlds-oldest-software-bugs ).